# How to copy a MSDE database to SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server, import, sql-server-2008-express, msde

We have a client environment that has MSDE. We're looking to install SQL Server 2008 Express on the clients but must retain MSDE for other applications.

Assuming both MSDE and SQL Server 2008 Express exist on a single machine what options are available to copy a database from MSDE to SQL Server 2008?

Suppose that MSDE may or may not be upgrade to SP4.

Once moved the database can be removed from MSDE. It's a one-time move.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Suppose that MSDE may or may not be
>   upgrade to SP4.

The SP4 requirement is only for in-place instance upgrade. For a side-by-side deployment and a detach-attach upgrade, SP4 is not required. All SQL 2000 SPs/RTM MSDE databases have the same physical format (v. 539, see this [Q&A](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.sqlqa.aspx)) so you can attach them to your SQL 2008 instance irrelevant of SP4 presence.